# Python pptx: how to find and delete the empty or unpopulated placeholders

Tags: python-2.7, python-pptx

I have created a presentation using python-pptx. However, some slides have the empty placeholders with default text `click to add title/text` that looks like the one below. [image]

So basically, there are non-empty placeholder with text `Some texts here` and other two are empty placeholders. How can I find and delete them? Also, there are same empty placeholders for images. How can I find them as well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Finding them is fairly easy; something roughly like this should do the trick:

```
for placeholder in slide.shapes.placeholders:
    if placeholder.has_text_frame and placeholder.text_frame.text == "":
        print("found one %s" % placeholder)
```

Deleting it is harder, because there is no direct API support for deleting shapes. However, in this simple case of text placeholders, this should work:

```
sp = placeholder._sp
sp.getparent().remove(sp)
```

The `._sp` attribute is the `lxml` `etree._Element` object representing the actual shape XML element (a placeholder `<p:sp>` element in this case). `.getparent()` and `.remove()` are methods on `etree._Element` and calling these manipulates the underlying XML directly. This can be dangerous, like if you tried this with a chart shape you'd probably get a repair error when you tried to load the presentation, but in this case it's safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

For blank slide, adjust the layout.

```
prs.slide_layouts[6]
```

Refer to the documentation (https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/slides.html), to see the different slide layouts.